# dijit.layout.TabContainer nested tabs auto load

Tags: dojo, dijit.layout

I'm fairly new to Dojo toolkit, and well really like it.  But I have a problem with nested tabs auto-refreshing.  Here is a sample of my practice code where this problem exists.  I'm currently concerned with this as it introduces a huge performance problem when the sub-tabs are plentiful; ex: my subtabs are the letters A-Z for initials for record retrieval.

I've tried all sorts of things to get around this, and all to no avail.

```
parseOnLoad=true/false
executeScripts=true/false
preload=true/false
nested=true/false
```

the parent page:

```
<div id="mainTabContainer" name="mainTabContainer" dojoType="dijit.layout.TabContainer" persist="true" style="margin:10px; width:800px; height:700px">
  <div
    id="tab1"
    name="tab1" 
    dojoType="dojox.layout.ContentPane" 
    title="DblClick" 
    selected="true" 
    closable="false" 
    parseOnLoad="true" 
    executeScripts="true"
    preload="false" 
    preventCache="true" 
    href="/dojo1.jsp?sParentTabID=tab1">
    ---
  </div>
  <div id="tab2" name="tab2" dojoType="dojox.layout.ContentPane" title="Read File" closable="false" executeScripts="true" parseOnLoad="true" href="/dojo2.jsp?sParentTabID=tab2">---</div>
  <div id="tab3" name="tab3" dojoType="dojox.layout.ContentPane" title="Form get/post" closable="false" executeScripts="true" parseOnLoad="true" href="/dojo3.jsp?sParentTabID=tab3">---</div>
  <div id="tab4" name="tab4" dojoType="dojox.layout.ContentPane" title="Accordions" closable="false" executeScripts="true" parseOnLoad="true" href="/dojo4.jsp?sParentTabID=tab4">---</div>
  <div id="tab5" name="tab5" dojoType="dojox.layout.ContentPane" title="Nested Tabs" closable="false" executeScripts="true" parseOnLoad="true" href="/dojo5.jsp?sParentTabID=tab5">---</div>
  <div id="tab6" name="tab6" dojoType="dojox.layout.ContentPane" title="Menu" closable="false" executeScripts="true" parseOnLoad="true" href="/dojo6.jsp?sParentTabID=tab6">---</div>
  <div id="tab7" name="tab7" dojoType="dojox.layout.ContentPane" title="Simple Objects" closable="false" extractContent="true" executeScripts="true" parseOnLoad="true" href="/dojo7.jsp?sParentTabID=tab7">---</div>
  <div id="tab8" name="tab8" dojoType="dojox.layout.ContentPane" title="Calendar" closable="false" extractContent="true" executeScripts="true" parseOnLoad="true" href="/dojo8.jsp?sParentTabID=tab8">---</div>
</div>
```

the child page (dojo5.jsp):

```
<div id="mainTabContainer_a4d6313" name="mainTabContainer_a4d6313" dojoType="dijit.layout.TabContainer" nested="true" style="width:95%;height:200px;">
  <div id="tab1_a4d6313" name="tab1_a4d6313" dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="First Tab"  selected="true" closable="false" href="/test.jsp?tabID=tab1_a4d6313">---</div>
  <div id="tab2_a4d6313" name="tab2_a4d6313" dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Second Tab" closable="true" href="/random.jsp?tabID=tab2_a4d6313">---</div>
  <div id="tab3_a4d6313" name="tab3_a4d6313" dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="AJAX Tab" closable="false" href="/random.jsp?tabID=tab3_a4d6313">---</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually working correctly in Dojo 1.4, which is almost released (you can grab the release candidate now).

I did a bunch of work a few months ago, refactoring the code to avoid problems like this.

Comment: Cool.  I'll try this later.  I ended up just created Dojo.form.buttons to simulate tabs, and each one just has it's one xhrGet method to fill in the DIV.  same result as what i was looking to do, just not as pretty without the tabs ... I'll try 1.4 thanks.

Is there a changelog / deprecated log somewhere for that too?